# How to find the contrapositive of this statement

Tags: logic

If the statement "all mimsy were the borogoves" is true, and the statement "the mome raths were outgrabe" is false, then what is the contrapositive of "If the borogoves were all mimsy, then the mome raths were *not* outgrabe"

Comment: It's "mome raths".  Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

I think the ambiguity, if ambiguity there be, comes from interpreting the statement about the mome raths.  If we say that the property of being outgrabe either pertains or does not pertain to the entire set of mome raths then the contrapositive is $$\text{"If the mome raths are not outgrabe then at least one borogrove is not mimsy"}$$.

If, instead, you imagine that the property of being outgrabe pertains to the individual members (hence might be true for some mome raths and false for others) and we say that the clause "the mome raths outgrabe" means that all mome raths have that property then the contrapositive would be $$\text{"if some mome raths are not outgrabe then at least one borogrove is not mimsy"}$$

Comment: Thank you, and what might be its truth value?

Comment: Oh, both it (and the equivalent original sentence) are false.  You have assured us that the mome raths are, alas, not outgrabe so were the statement true we'd have to be able to find at least one non-mimsy borogrove but as we can't (again as per your assurance) then the statement is false.